# Telegram ReplyKeyboardMarkup, send different text that is displayed on the button

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to use ReplyKeyboardMarkup with the following code:

```
replyKeyboardMakeup = '{"keyboard": [["Done","Done 2"], ["Update"], ["Log Time"]],"one_time_keyboard": true}'
```

But I was wondering if it is possible to send a different command than the one displayed on the buttons. For example, a button would display "Help me!" but the command sent by the user would be /help actually.

Is that possible in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to send different data. Bot will get the text as shown to the users.
If you want to hide the text or something like that, you could use the [InlineKeyboardButton](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.inlinekeyboardbutton.html?highlight=inlinekeyboard#telegram.InlineKeyboardButton)